# CloudSQL Server Stuck in maintenance mode

Tags: maintenance-mode

I have a google cloud SQL 2nd gen instance stuck in maintenance mode. 
It has binary logging disabled.

I can't access the users, databases or restart the instance. It is well outside the maintenance window (by days) and has been in this state for over 12 hours.

What can I do to regain control over it?

Comment: Did you managed to solve this @Adrian ?

Comment: nope, the database is still in maintenance mode. I can access it and it does not appear to be slow. But I can't do anything through the console, like restart the server etc. Will probably have to re-deploy.

Comment: I'm in the same exact situation. I dumped the DB thought ssh and I'm planning to create another instance to deploy or maybe switch to another SQL host, as Google didn't give me any support for this.